# How can this mass go off the edge of a disk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force

If a mass rests at the edge of a disk, where friction acts on it, and the disk is rotated with an angular velocity just enough for this mass to slide out, then the linear velocity of the mass $v$ is given by

$$\dfrac{mv^2}{R} = \mu_{\rm static}mg$$

Well, I don't understand why. It doesn't make sense to me because shouldn't this be the force to just counter-act the friction? How can the mass move if there is no acceleration to make the mass go that minimal amount off the disk?

Comment: If you add a minimal amount of acceleration (ie make the disk spin just a little faster), doesn't the mass slip off the disk then? The extra acceleration can be as small as you choose, to make the LHS bigger than the RHS.

Comment: Do you understand what u ( that is more normally $\mu$ ) is, coefficient of friction?

Answer (score 1):

You equation $$\dfrac{mv_{\rm maximum}^2}{R} = \mu_{\rm static}mg$$ gives you the maximum speed that the mass can have without it sliding.

Any greater speed will result in $\dfrac{mv^2}{R} > \mu_{\rm static}mg$ and so the mass will slide relative to the disc and move off the disc.

Suppose that you found that the maximum speed was $4.32 \, \rm m\, s^{-1}$ and at this speed the mass did not slide.

So a speed of $4.320000....0000001 \, \rm m\, s^{-1}$, ie very slightly greater than the "just not sliding" speed, would give rise to sliding but you might as well call this speed $4.32 \, \rm m\, s^{-1}$ which is accurate enough for most/all purposes?

Answer (score 1):

The mass is accelerating inward toward the center of the disk.  If it were not accelerating, it would be traveling in a straight line (not a circle).  The magnitude of the inward (radial) acceleration is $a=v^2/R$.

The frictional force F is causing the mass to accelerate inward.  So, from Newton's 2nd law of motion, $$ma=m\frac{v^2}{R}=F$$ When the frictional force F exceeds the normal force mg times the coefficient of static friction $\mu_{static}$, the mass can begin to slide relative to the disk.